# "svchost.exe cannot be allowed through firewall" ftp server

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

Alright here's my problem iv recently set up an ftp server and everything works fine except when i try to allow svchost.exe through the firewall, I get the error message "windows cannot allow svchost through firewall". If i disable the firewall there are no problems but i would rather have the firewall up (for obvious reasons) can anyone please tell me why it is not allowing the application through the firewall and how to fix? Or what i may have done wrong to receive this message as all the tutorials iv seen do not have this issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't use FTP. [FTP Must Die](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).

Answer (score 1):

I think that you misunderstand what `svchost.exe` is. [This article](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-vista/What-is-svchost-exe), which is for Vista, is still relevant.

svchost is a process that hosts windows services. There are many instances of it on a system at a given time and each one hosts a different service. **You don't want to allow svchost through your firewall**. This will essentially expose *any* service that needs to perform an action and gets encapsulated in an svchost.exe process.

This is *not* the way to solve the issue that you're having. You should use port-based rules to allow FTP, not executable-based rules.

Comment: If you add the FTP Server role to the Web Server role on W2K8 and W2K8R2 it does in fact create several FTP inbound rules which are bound to svchost.exe targeted at the service with the short name FTPSVC.

Comment: Really? I never realized that. Seems I need to dig into the pre-configured Windows Firewall settings a bit more.

Comment: Yeah. It seemd kind of weird to me, but I haven't dug into the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security very much at this point. The rules appear to be "combo" rules consisting of both port, program and service parameters. Since they're created automatically they aren't editable but you can view the parameters. In fact, most of the automatically created rules (based on the installed roles, role services and features) seem to have similar parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guy's and while there's good info here I still don't understand how i can get passed this. Iv tried adding new rules for inbound traffic with the advanced firewall config but still no luck, atm it's not a huge issue but i would very much like to understand what im doing wrong here.

Comment: @Anthony It might help if you explain the actual problem that you're trying to solve rather than just the error that you're getting.

Comment: ok no problem im setting up a file server and installed the AD DC, DNS, File Services and IIS roles, within the network i can use the internal IP and log on fine, externally=nothing. I since learnt that i need to allow the svchost.exe application through my firewall (in tutorials iv watched on setting up an ftp server this was no problem) but the firewall wont accept it through for me. This has happened on several servers iv attempted this with which leads me to believe that its some configuration somewhere that im doing incorrectly. But I have no idea what this could be?

Comment: [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsGPqkobCs8&hd=1) this is the tutorial i followed..

Comment: I apologize for any inconvenience as im still pretty new to Windows server and networking..

Comment: There's already a pre-configured Windows Firewall rule for FTP-In. What's wrong with just enabling that?

Comment: There is indeed unfortunately it is already enabled by default and does not seem to allow external connections..

Comment: Then your problem is elsewhere. The default firewall rule is all that you need to enable. Are you sure you're enabling that rule on the correct firewall profile?

Comment: No im not to be honest how would i find out the correct profile?

Comment: There are three default profiles: Domain, Public, and Private and which one is active depends on your network settings. You should either ask a new question about it, or read the manual on technet.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice will check up on it now.